# Parsing thru SOAPMessage response, convert it to String XML and get Node values

Tags: java, xml, soap, xml-parsing

I am using this method for converting a SOAPMessage response to XML String. After converting I need to get particular nodes values.

```html
    /**
  * Method used to convert the response to XML string
  */
     private String getSOAPResponseString(SOAPMessage soapResponse) throws Exception {
  StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
  TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
  Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
  Source sourceContent = soapResponse.getSOAPPart().getContent();
  StreamResult result = new StreamResult(sw);
  transformer.transform(sourceContent, result);
  //System.out.println(sw.toString());
  //System.out.println(soapResponse.getMimeHeaders());
  return sw.toString();
 }
```

I check for this Node from the XML String.But it is not always coming as

```html
String responseMsg = response.substring(response.indexOf("<providerReturnMessage>") + "<providerReturnMessage>".length() ,            response.indexOf("</providerReturnMessage>"));
```

sometimes it has a prefix in front of it like this
    `<axis2ns7:providerReturnMessage>, <axis2ns8:providerReturnMessage>` , How can I read the message text in this Node ignoring the prefix in front.

Comment: `get SOAPMessage` object as it is not the string, then get the body and search for the element you want

Comment: `responseBody.getElementsByTagName("providerReturnMessage").item(0).getTextContent();`  this errors out as there is no such node, it has a prefix in front of it.